# Handle bar height

Tags: bike-fit

I have a commuter bike whose handle bars are too low, causing me to have to lean forward more than I'd like. I do not wish to have sore shoulders or neck pain from riding with my head forward. Would sitting entirely upright help, or should I still have some weight on my arms? Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think the handle bars are too low? Are you getting neck and shoulder pain?

Comment: What is comfortable for you is what's comfortable for you.  Most people who complain about shoulder/neck pain as you do will benefit from any elevation of the handlebar, though it's hard to predict how much would be significant enough to be worth the effort.  Plus it often the case that the bike frame is a hair too big or the stem places the bar too far forward, so the long "reach" is as much a problem as the low bar.

Comment: (But it's my opinion that bike manufacturers deliver bikes with the bar set too low because that makes them look "meaner" on the salesfloor.  And with the new threadless headsets it's not as easy to raise the handlebar once you have the bike in your possession.)

Comment: As a flat-bar/commuter rider I'd say that "too low" for comfort is when you have to tip your head back to see where you're going. A road-bike regular would disagree. It's not the sort of thing you can really worry much about until you start pushing the distance and finding what aches.

Answer (score 1):

Sitting *entirely* upright might cause back pain! Ideally, you want your back to have a bit of an arch and your elbows a bit of a bend, to help your back and arms absorb bumps in the road.

Having very little weight over the front axle can make steering feel floaty, and could be an issue under hard braking. Your weight should be comfortably distributed across your hands, feet, and butt on the saddle.

In the end, do whatever you find is most comfortable for *you...* whatever gets you out and riding! Try adjusting the height of the bars and saddle in small increments until you find what works best.

Answer (score 0):

I own several bikes that all have different stems lengths and angles. The geometry of each bike is different due to the age of the bike and the type of riding. I purchased an adjustable stem. I got it used for about $15. They are available new for about $25. I only use it to figure out what stem will be comfortable. I can change the angle and move the spacers from below the stem to above it, to simulate different lengths. I can then purchase a stem with close to the same dimensions. Several friends have used it with decent results.